# How to remove existing validation rule in mdb from visual basic

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to remove existing ValidationRule property which resides in the TABLE from vba programatically. I am unaware the constraint name too.

[image]

I opted to print table informations. So that i can add the constraint name in alter statement.
Please let me know if u feel the question is not clear

Comment: I know this not helpful at all, but why do you want to do it via vba and not just highlight it and delete it? I don't believe there is an `alter table` or anything you can do for it. The only work around I could think of is to write vba to create a new table named the same without validation and append the data to it, and remove the prior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine and/or modify a field's `ValidationRule` property by referencing the field name in the table's `Fields` collection.

Here is a sample Immediate window session ...

```
' display existing rule
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").Fields("a_number").ValidationRule
<999
' discard rule
CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").Fields("a_number").ValidationRule = ""
' verify rule gone
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").Fields("a_number").ValidationRule

' that last command printed an empty string
```

The `ValidationRule` property is not implemented as a named constraint and it can not be altered with a SQL DDL statement.